# How to deselect multiple jcheckboxes in java according text it containing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

The code that i have is the following:

```
for(cond)
{

    if(j.getText().equals(some text)
    j.setSelected(false);

}
```

Comment: Could you give some more code and more explanation of what you want?

Comment: Can you be more clear?

Comment: What exactly is the question here?

Comment: please provide more info about your checkboxes and what are you trying to do

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to check some `JCheckbox`es text and uncheck. If you added your `JCheckbox`es inside a `JPanel` you can use this,

```
for (int i = 0; i < jPanel1.getComponentCount(); i++) {    
    JCheckBox check =   (JCheckBox) jPanel1.getComponent(i);
    if(check.getText().equals("check")){
      check.setSelected(false);
    }
}
```